# Android PushSharp Notification message trimming

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, pushsharp

I am using PushSharp to push notifications on Android. But in Android notification center, long message gets trimmed with "...".
Here is the image of notification text trimming:

http://s10.postimg.org/3uoszl7cp/notification_Length.png

My code to push notification:

```
                var push = new PushBroker();
                push.RegisterGcmService(new GcmPushChannelSettings("API Key here"));
                foreach (Device device in lstDevices)
                {
                    push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(device.Token)
                             .WithJson("{\"message\":\"" + NotificationMessage + "\",\"sound\":\"sound.caf\"}"));
                }
```

Is there a way to make the notification text break into new line without trimming?

Answer (score 0):

This is handled in the android application code,the developer decides how much text will be shown in the notification and how to handle the long text,you can't do it from your code